# Can two non-commuting matrices be commuting after projection?

Tags: linear-algebra

For two matrices A and B, $[A,B] \neq 0$, and there is a third matrix C, where $[C,A]=0, [C,B]=0$. Now suppose C has lot of distinct eigenvalues. I select those eigenvectors (more than 1) with eigenvalue $c_0$ to construct a projection operator: P = $\sum|c_0><c_0|$. My question is whether $[PAP,PBP] \neq 0$ or not or it depends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=diag(A_1,A_2), B=diag(B_1,B_2)$, and assume $A_1,B_1$ commutes, $A_2, B_2$ does not commute. Assume $P_1=C_1=diag(I,O)$ and $P_2=C_2=diag(O,I)$.

Obviously $P_i$ commutes with $A$ and $B$ respectively. The results are different.